# Send a single message on Discord JS (v12)

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im not able to send a single message from my bot using Discord JS as of v12.

I think before the update (v11) was able just by calling the `channel.send('text here')` but now I do not how to do it.

In detail: I want to send a message upon the bot connection and **not only** when someone sends a message; meaning that Im only able to send a message using the `client.on('message', msg =>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages anytime, as long as the bot is connected and ready.

The only reason why you say you "can't" send messages outside of the message event is because in the message event, you listen for a message event and respond to that message in the same channel.

You want to know how to send a message without a pre-existing message.

Go to the desired channel, right-click it, and click Copy ID. (If Developer Mode isn't on, turn it on in user settings.)

If you are using discord.js v12, use `client.channels.cache.get('theChannelID').send('yourmessage');` or if you are using discord.js v11, delete the cache part.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. One last thing, by any chance wouldnt you know how to stream something too? Like play some audio whenever it joins (I do know how to use the dispacher and stuff but idk how to let it interact with the channel without an user message. Thanks anyway for you previous answer!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to message the same channel of the user's mess, try using `message.channel.send(content)`